# Bumps on carbon steel seasoning, can I repair it

Tags: seasoning-pans, carbon-steel

I've just got a new De Buyer carbon steel pan and I'm 3 seasons in (oven method) and I'm noticing quite an uneven surface (especially little bubbles). I've tried as best as possible to keep the layers of oil used very thin. I'm wondering if I should strip it down and start over or just forge ahead?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are fine.  I personally feel the best way to continue to season a pan is to actually just to cook in it.  The first things I like after the oven or range top seasoning is to use onions, green onions and other inexpensive ingredients.  Perhaps also to deep fry some onion rings or french fries as well.  This will have the correct heat and also plenty of oil to seep into the pan.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As JGsd said, use the pan.  But I'd also suggest using metal utensils, so you scrape away the high spots.

But in looking at your picture, I'd say that you had too much oil per layer.  You want to heat up the pan, add oil, wait just a little bit, and then wipe away as much of it as you can.

If you wipe down the pan while the oil is cold, it's a little more viscous, and you leave a little bit too much oil.  It then thins out as it heats up but will form patterns like what I'm seeing in your picture.

Answer (score -1):

How are you seasoning it?  I just seasoned my mew carbon steel and looove it.

You need to wipe alllll the oil out of it after applying it.  It look as though you put it in the oven right side up with oil still in it.

Put it in the self.clean oven cycle to strip it.  Tske it out when cooled and wash down.

I tried flaxseed oil and wasn't impressed.  I mixed crisco, red palm oil, ans grapeseed oil.  Put the pan in the oven at 200F for 10 mins.  Take out and rub down really well.  Now wipe it all off.  Think its all.off? Tske a paper towel and wipe it again.  Put in oven for 1 hour at 475 and let cool.  Repeat.

Im a first time cast iron user and repeated this process 7 times with my 2 new skillets one is cast iron one is carbon steel and they csme oit gorgeous and completely non stick.  Then i restored 2 old pans and only did this process 3 times and theyre both completely non stick and gorgeous
[image]